# Opening VSCode from the command line in WSL2

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, vscode-remote

In WSL2, if I am in any folder like `/mnt/c/*` and I type `code .` VSCode opens properly.

However, if I am in any Linux folder e.g, `/home/<user>` etc. and I type `code .` then VSCode doesn't open. I just see a blinking cursor on a new line and absolutely nothing else happens.

When I run it with `VSCODE_WSL_DEBUG_INFO=true code .` it appears that this is the line on which it is failing:

`ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 /mnt/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe C:/Users/<users>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js --locate-extension ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl`

Thoughts on what could be going on?

Comment: what's the output of echo $PATH?
It's probably not registered in your Linux path

Comment: PATH includes /mnt/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin and typing "which code" also gives me /mnt/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code